# How to rotate a bone to certain way depending on an other bone?

Tags: armature

Lets say there are two separate bones placed as V.

Lets think bottom of V as pivot point.

When I rotate left bone to the left I want to right side of V to be rotate right and vice versa.

I tried several constrains but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have this correct you are trying to open and close the V shape using 1 bone. If this is so and the V doesn't perfectly line up with the **global** axis you are rotating around than first you must see if the **local** axis of the bones line up.

In *Pose Mode* go to *Object Data Properties*  (little green man), go to *Viewport Display* tab and check *Axes* (move the *Position* to get a better look). If either the X axis of Z axis are lined up create a *Rotation Constraint* on one bone, set the *Target* and *Owner* to *Local Space* and check the *Invert* for the *Local Axis* you are rotating around.

This will require you to rotate in *Local Mode* but if the object only rotates on this one axis then make sure that the control bone is rotation locked to only the axis you want it to use.

Comment: There is no **Rotation Constrain** but using **Copy Rotation** it could be done. Thank you for inspiration :).