# How do I let two bones tails rotate to a pivot

Tags: armature, bones

[image: pic1]
I want the tails of both bones to approach the same point.

`Copy Rotation` constraint from url https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/285415/168173 . After setting, the bone position will be immediately modified, which is not what I want.
*It seems that the two bones will be completely symmetrical*

More explanation.
[image: pic2]

What I want to do.

- Select 2 bones.
- Press some keys or what ?
- After moving the mouse, the bones move as shown in Figure 2

Example file(pic2): [image]